# Why tf.keras dosen't work but tensorflow.keras does even though tensorflow is imported as tf?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've used the following lines of code:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
```

`from tensorflow.keras import models`- this works fine

BUT

When `from tf.keras import models` is used, error appears

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-15abaed607f8> in <module>()
----> 1 from tf.keras import models

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

***Why*** is this happening?

Comment: The name of the package is tensorflow, not tf, tf is just an alias that people use, it is not the actual package name.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are stored in the computers as folders. For example, there is a xgboost folder if you import that. When you type

```
from tf.keras import models
```

Python will look for a 'tf' reference (package) in your system, which does not exist, tf just exist as an alias in your python IDE.